# How to make it so you only have to authenticate once for a group of subdomains using a Apache virtual host?

Tags: virtualhost, apache2, http-authentication

I have a Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Server with a set of virtual host configurations that protect a group of subdomains using basic auth, for example lets say secure.example.com is password protected as well as [www.secure.example.com](http://www.secure.example.com), sub.secure.example.com and [www.sub.secure.example.com](http://www.sub.secure.example.com) however my issue is that it asks you to reauthenticate every time you change subdomain for example if you go from secure.example.com to [www.secure.example.com](http://www.secure.example.com) it will ask you to reauthenticate which is not desired how do I make it so that authentication is valid for a certain set of subdomains so you only have to authenticate once for this set of subdomains?

Example VirtualHost configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName secure.example.com
    ServerAlias www.secure.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/secure.example.com/public_html

    <Directory /var/www/secure.example.com/public_html/>
        AuthName "Restricted Content"
        AuthType Basic
        AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
        Require valid-user

        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basic authentication passes the password with every request. Allowing the browser to reuse the entered password for a different host would be a massive security risk.

So no, that is not possible.